# PHP require_once not working

Tags: php, adodb, require-once

I am new on PHP can you tell me what it is wrong with this line:

```
require_once 'autoloader.php';
echo "2";
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once __ROOT__.'/_3parties/adodb/adodb-lib.inc.php';
echo "3";
```

The page display only 2 but not 3. I have a folder with adodb library.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you will also see some error ... Maybe you are referring to invalid path

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
require_once 'autoloader.php';
echo "2";
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

echo "This is my path";
echo __ROOT__.'/_3parties/adodb/adodb-lib.inc.php';
require_once (__ROOT__.'/_3parties/adodb/adodb-lib.inc.php');
echo "3";
```

Comment: Check the ECHOed path .. verify it is valid or not

Comment: Thank you so much. I put the line you tell me, but there is not error displayed.

Comment: try this
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I gave my permission and still nothing :(

Comment: I am woring in Windows this might be a problem